# Qubeks logic game - is it solvable in random initial state?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I've been making a new logic game for the last few months - a 3D puzzle game called QUBEKS. You can find more details about it on the web page www.qubeks.com and you can play the 2D game in the user area, but I will also try to explain the game concept here.

Imagine a cube with six faces where each of the faces can be assigned a single color state from an ordered set of colors. Cube can be rotated around two horizontal axes x & y and one vertical axis z, perpendicular to the cube faces. When rotating the cube around one of the horizontal axes, the two perpendicular faces will change their color to the next one in the color set, if the face was rotated clockwise with regard to the axis of rotation, or will go back to the previous color if rotated counterclockwise. In this case there are always two opposite faces involved, which change color states in opposite directions.
Only exception is rotation around the vertical axis: in this case only the top face will change its color state, while the bottom face which cannot be seen because the cube is resting on it, will not change state.

When the color state reaches the beginning or the end of the ordered color set, it is going to loop correspondingly to the end or the beginning of the set.

The math problem I have is that I want to start the Qubeks game with randomized color states on all faces. However, at this moment I am not sure if I can always solve a randomly shuffled Qubeks game within finite number of moves, so in my algorithm (both in the physical prototype and in the online game on the website) I always start from a situation where all faces of the QUbeks cube have the same color state and I randomly shuffle it from there. In this way I am sure that there is a solution if I go backwards in the shuffling sequence and select the opposite moves (shuffling sequence can be seen in the online 2D QUbeks game).

What kind of math theory (game theory, set theory, combinatorial theory etc. ) should I use if I want to prove that with this set of rules I could solve all randomly selected combinations of color states on the Qubeks cube? Or should I go the "computational way" and try different combinations until I find one that I cannot solve with a computer, so that I prove at least the opposite - that not all combinations are solvable. But then how can I be sure that there is no solution, it is maybe only a weakness of the solver algorithm? Or I should just try all possible moves, but this might take long time and computational resources? I am a bit in doubt in which direction to go, because I would like to understand even better the math theory behind the Qubeks cube puzzle.

I hope somebody out there could help with the mathematics theory of the Qubeks game.

Best regards,
Petar

Comment: Basically this looks like you have a game where you are allowed to perform certain permutations and are required to order the items up. In that aspect it's similar to Rubiks cube (but no more than that). I'd guess that there are permutations that aren't reachable for the same reason there are on Rubiks cube.

Comment: It doesn't seem there is a way to change just one of the two colors on opposite sides, so this is impossible if the colors are different to start

Comment: @JasonCarr You can change the top side color individually.